# Using UITextView in UITableViewController - tap outside to dismiss keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

I'm using a text view inside a table cell. Other cells are associated with segues so I need the following behaviour:

1. (Default) Tapping on other table rows triggers relevant segue
2. Tapping inside the text view begins editing and shows the keyboard
3. If the keyboard is visible, tapping outside the text view dismisses the keyboard but does not follow segues
4. Once the keyboard has been dismissed, subsequent taps on segues are followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Adopt the `textView` delegate method and**

```
textView.delegate = self
```

**2. Add global property**

`var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()`

**3. Implement the `textView` delegate methods**

`func textViewDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextView) {
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.Tapped))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }`

`func textViewDidEndEditing(textField: UITextView) {
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }`

**4. Implement the Tapped()**

`func Tapped(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }`

Note : This also works for UITextField, replacing View with Field throughout

Comment: This is simpler than my solution but is for UITextField rather than UITextView. I assume it could be altered replacing Field with View?

Answer (score 0):

Add the UITextViewDelegate protocol to your class and add these variables

```
var textViewIsEditing:Bool = false
var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
```

Override the viewdidload function so that the tableViewController listens for events from the text view.

Also add a UITapGestureRecognizer which will trigger a custom handleTap function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTextView.delegate = self

    tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.handleTap))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}
```

Add two functions to toggle textViewIsEditing based on whether the textview is being edited

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    textViewIsEditing = false
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    textViewIsEditing = true
}
```

Now add a custom handleTap function to decide how to handle taps:

```
func handleTap(thisGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    if(textFieldIsEditing){
        // ignore this tap if editing text field but end editing
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        view.endEditing(true)
    }else{
        // proceed as normal
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    }

}
```